# Why is Cassano called the "Devil of the Right Arm"?

Tags: tower-of-god

In the chapter 136, it shows Cassano saying:

[image: Cassano appears!]

Why is Cassano referred to as the "Devil of the Right Arm" and not Horyang?

They both have the same "devil" inside them, but Horyang has it on his right side:

[image: The Devil appears!]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though Horyang made a name for himself as the "devil of the right arm", he stopped climbing the tower after reaching the 20th floor (as he explains in chapter 122, page 28). Cassano, who appeared later, rode on Horyang's fame and borrowed his fearsome "title". People mistook Cassano for the real "devil of the right arm"; some people, including Koon's party, are searching for this newly appeared "devil of the right arm".

Comment: So, The "real" Devil of the right arm was Horyang, not Cassano. But Cassano "borrowed" his title?!

Comment: I don't have an official source for this, but I am inferring from previous chapters that either Cassano knowingly "borrowed" the title or people mistook his abilities (that were similar to Horyang's) and Cassano never bothered to correct them.